# Quarto table cross-reference gt

Tags: r, r-markdown, cross-reference, gt, quarto

```
 ---
title: "example"
format: 
  pdf: 
    documentclass: article
editor: visual
---
```

Hello everyone i have a simple problem which is driving me crazy: I want cross reference a table created by a gt table using a caption. Here is my setup:

````
     ```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
tbl_1 <- tribble(~x, ~y,
                 1, 2,
                 3, 4)

      ```
````

And lets say i want to create a table from tbl_1 and cross reference it later. Here is my attempt:

````
```{r}
#| label: tbl-table-1
#| tbl-cap: "table 1"

tbl_1 %>% gt()
```
````

This gives me:

```
compilation failed- error
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\caption): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.227 \caption
              {\label{tbl-table-1}table 1 } 

see example.log for more information.
```

And if i use the caption argument in the gt function it gives me nothing.

````
```{r}
#| label: tbl-table-1
tbl_1 %>% gt(caption = "table 1")

```
````

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnNT6.png)

Does anyone know of a solution or perhaps im doing something wrong?

Comment: It works fine for output other than pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue in Quarto that has been fixed now
https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/924

Using **gt** with caption and cross reference should work as espected now if you use Quarto version above 0.9.439

Note that there is still some improvement to be done to **gt** LaTeX output to be fully compliant with Quarto output and features. Following **gt** releases will be the best to know when those improvement will be made.