# Table referencing with Quarto and gt

Tags: quarto

I can't seem to give a table made with `gt()` a caption with Quarto and hence I can't cross-reference it. Using `kable()` works fine though. Minimal example here:

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
#| include: false
library(gt)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| label: tbl-mytable
#| tbl-cap: "Caption"
head(mtcars) %>% gt()
```

@tbl-mytable

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| label: tbl-mytable2
#| tbl-cap: "Caption"
head(mtcars) %>% kable()
```

@tbl-mytable2
````

From what I could tell, `gt` should be supported by Quarto, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me it renders as expected, maybe you need to update quarto since there has been a bug in the past (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251411/quarto-table-cross-reference-gt).

Comment: @Julian: That's weird. I saw that bug, but thought I was in the clear since I'm running Quarto version 1.3.142. What version are you using?

Comment: Alright, seems to be an issue with the pre-release version I'm running since it works with Quarto version 1.1. I'll go ahead and file a bug report.

Comment: This is fixed in the newest Quarto versions.